# "Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! : when trying to host LLM as Sagemaker endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

Trying to host LLM as sagemaker endpoint for text generation but running into above mentioned error while predicting

I have moved the model and tensors to cuda if, it is available as below -

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
nlp_model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_dir, torch_dtype=torch.float16)
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
nlp_model.to(device)
input_ids.to(device)
```

Then this throw the error - Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select

Comment: Which line throws the error specifically?

Comment: Please share a full stack trace.